# ExecutorService does not run tasks in parallel

Tags: java, forkjoinpool

I have a recursive bulk task that I put into execution in a ForkJoinPool thread pool.

```
public class SomeTask extends RecursiveAction {
    @Override
    protected void compute() {
       //Some recursive logic...
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startForkJoinPool();
    }

    private void startForkJoinPool() {
       SomeTask someTask = new SomeTask();

       ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
       pool.invoke(someTask);
       pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Now I need to execute this logic in two more parallel threads.

I decided to try to use the ExecutorService thread pool, and when I put entities into it for execution, I found out that they are not executed in parallel, but, as it were, one of the threads is parked for the duration of the first one.

```
public class SomeTask extends RecursiveAction {
    @Override
    protected void compute() {
       //Some recursive logic...
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
        threadList.add(new Thread(() -> startForkJoinPool()));
        threadList.add(new Thread(() -> startForkJoinPool()));

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        threadList.forEach(executorService::execute);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    private void startForkJoinPool() {
       SomeTask someTask = new SomeTask();

       ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
       pool.invoke(someTask);
       pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Tell me, please, what can I do wrong?
Many thanks in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Change `execute` to `submit`.
- Await termination when shutting down an executor service.

## `Executor#execute` is not necessarily async

You need to carefully read the documentation. This is a tricky area.

The `ExecutorService#execute` method is inherited from the super interface [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)).

The Javadoc for `Executor` says:

> However, the `Executor` interface does not strictly require that execution be asynchronous

So any `Runnable` you pass to [`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) may or *may not* be run on a background thread.

## `ExecutorService#submit` is always async

If you definitely want your `Runnable` to run on a background thread, pass to [`ExecutorService#submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)).

Change this line:

```
threadList.forEach(executorService::execute);
```

… to this:

```
threadList.forEach(executorService::submit);
```

## Shutdown

Your call to `ExecutorService#shutdown` is insufficient. You need to wait for submitted tasks to complete.

See the boilerplate method `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` given to you in the Javadoc for [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Or, in Java 19+, call [`ExecutorService#close`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#close()).

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit strange that your code example contains ExecutorService.invoke and ExecutorService.execute where you should be calling [ExecutorService.submit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)).

The [ExecutorService documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) also contains a usage example.
And then there is some nice [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create any threads, that is the job of the ExecutorService.

You don't want to `execute` the task, you want to `submit` the task. Then you get a `Future<T>` returned.

As you already have a collection, consider `invokeAll` that returns `List<Future<T>>` and saves you iterating through your list.